# How to aggregate (using "by") a data.table with customized column name without ":="?

Tags: r, data.table

I know I can do this

```
  a <- dt[,sum(x), by=y]
```

Also I can do this

```
  dt[,z:=sum(x), by=y] # this would modify dt
```

However I don't get why I cannot do this:

```
  a <- dt[,z=sum(x), by=y]
```

How should I perform a "summarize" with customized column names?

Is this the only option?

```
  a <- copy(dt)
  a[,z:=sum(x), by=y]
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You're looking for `list()` in the `j` argument:

```
a <- dt[,list(z=sum(x)), by=y]
```

Comment: Even there is only 1 column? It is weird this time `dt[,list(z:=sum(x)), by=y]` doesn't work

Comment: @colinfang `:=` is the assignment operator - but you don't want to assign anything, you're just extracting a list of things from the `data.table` and want to give names to the list - thus the syntax

Comment: Yeah `:=` is a `data.table` function, so it doesn't have any meaning inside a `list` argument. Just use `list(z=sum(x))`, and only use `:=` when trying to add a column to an existing table.

Comment: You can't write `z=` in the second position of `dt[,,]` because that function call (to `?\`[.data.table\``) doesn't have an argument named z. I couldn't find a standard reference on passing by name vs position, but there's [this blog post](http://blog.moertel.com/posts/2006-01-20-wondrous-oddities-rs-function-call-semantics.html).